# Angular Component: How Ensure Callback Defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm using Angular *Components* which were introduced with v1.5.

GOAL: If **& bindings** callbacks aren't specified by a parent view html template, I'd like to display a warning in the browser console, alerting the developer that the expected and necessary properties haven't been specified in the component they are using.

QUESTION: How do I ensure that **& bindings** (which function as callbacks to component events) are defined, so that I can aid future developers toward quick debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if you specify the binding as `'&?'` then you can use `typeof` to check it is a function.

Answer (score -1):

Simply check in the component controller if the type of the property is a function.

```
angular
    .module('moduleName')
    .component('compName', {
        controller: function() {
            if (typeof this.myFunc !== 'function') {
                console.warn('myFunc not defined!');
            }
        },
        bindings: {
            myFunc: '&'
        }
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  In this example, `this.myFunc` is of type function.  And it looks like:  `function (locals) { return parentGet(scope, locals);  }`

Comment: Also, I'm using Angular v1.5.8.